# Can't elevate for administrator actions

Tags: uac, windows-server-2012-r2

My computer's OS appears to not be letting me run anything elevated. Anything I try that requires it eventually errors out, typically with a "*path* The specified module could not be found" error. This includes the essentials dashboard, mmc, and powershell. Stuff that's not elevated runs fine: notepad, internet explorer, crashplan dashboard, etc. I can't figure it out, and Google isn't helping enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the problem is that the SSD the OS was installed on was losing it's mind, and corrupted various parts of the install.